# Dynamically set datasource for jquery datatable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatables

Is there a way we can dynamically set data source of datatable columns? Like I set `columns.data` by hardcoding each property name like this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    url: urlGetProviderQualificationTimeData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (obj) {
        if (obj.success) {
            $('#tblProds').dataTable({
            data: obj.data.ProdsDetails,
            columns: [
                { "data": "PName" },
                { "data": "PTime" }  //hardcoded mapping of properties     
            ]
            });
        }
    },
});
```

`ProdsDetails` sample array:

```
Array[2]
0:Object
    PName:"ATT",
    PTime:"6.48"   
1:Object
    PName:"CENTURYLINK",
    PTime:"3.67"
```

Is there a way we can get rid of this hardcoded mapping of properties and columns?

Comment: You want to set properties which you received from `ajax` call ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai exactly without specifying the property names

Comment: Where do you want to get the properties from? From `obj.data`? Show us the array please.

Comment: @Andy `obj.data.ProdsDetails`

Comment: Then you can simply loop trough the array and create a new one. Please add an example of the array to the question so we can help you properly

Comment: As @Andy said, please update your post with `json` array.

Comment: @FactFinder, `ProviderName` is the column name ?

Comment: @FactFinder, also see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try to resolve your problem.

Comment: @FactFinder, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your array :

```
var array=[
             {PName:"ATT",PTime:"6.48" },
             {PName:"CENTURYLINK",PTime:"3.67"}
          ];
```

Now, You should get all the `keys` and build final array:

```
var obj=array[0];
var keys=[];
for(var k in obj) 
    keys.push({"data":k});
```

Now, `keys` array looks like this:

```
[
   {"data":"PName"},
   {"data":"PTime"}
]
```

And the last step is to assign array to `columns` property of `DataTable`:

```
columns:keys
```

Now this should look like this:

```
columns:[
          { "data": "PName" },
          { "data": "PTime" }    
]
```

Hope this helps !.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and worked around this by creating an extra `json` array for the `columns.data` property. Is used a `php` function to loop through the headers and put it into a `json` array.

Comment: had this thing in mind. But that's a work around. I was wondering if we have anything that could solve the problem

Comment: True, I don't think this is possible at the moment. I just checked the website and can't find anything about this.